# Mysql select and count in one Order by Case when...query

Tags: mysql

I have this database table: `membership`

```
id   name       email               level      memberdate
1    Joe        joe@gmail.com       silver     04/09/2015
2    Peter      perter@gmail.com    bronze     05/09/2015
3    John       john@gmail.com      gold       06/09/2015
4    Jack       jack@gmail.com      bronze     09/09/2015
```

I used this query to display people with level= bronze firstly.

```
select * 
from membership 
order by 
  case 
    when level = 'bronze' then 1 
    else 2
  end,
  memberdate desc;
```

Moreover, I would like to count how many people with level = `bronze` in the same query above. The count result should be 2 in this case. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: use count function like `count(lavel)`

Comment: 1) You could simply use `order by level` since `b` comes before `s` and `g`;
2) you might want to reconsider using this query for that; you will get redundant data. It's more clear to use `select level, count(*) from membership group by level`.

Comment: Please edit your question and show your expected output.  It is not clear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *, (select sum(level = 'bronze') from membership) as bronze_count
from membership 
order by case when level = 'bronze' then 1 else 2 end,
         memberdate desc
```

Comment: is this going to be more efficient than using the first select * query, then next query  just to select level= bronze and use rowCount()?

Comment: how can i echo $bronze_count before foreach loop??

Comment: You can run the queries seperately. does not make much difference

Comment: After i execute the query, I would like to echo the variable bronze_count before i run foreach($result as $row){ ....}. How can i do that?

Comment: I am not a PHP expert.